# What is the delay for an Azure function to be triggered for EventHub?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am using a Standard App Service plan for a bunch of my Azure functions. My functions read from EventHubs and forward data to another destination. However they seem either not triggered or when they are, only after a long delay (ten minutes or more).
This happened to both Azure-created EventHubs (like insights-operational-logs for Activity Logs) and my own. I was able to send and receive data from these EventHubs almost instantly using my own sender and receiver clients (e.g with https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-node), so there is data there in the hubs.

So my questions are: 
 1. What's the typical delay for the trigger?
 2. How do I know if my functions are triggered for all events (or how do I debug for that case)? 
 3. How do I configure the triggering to be fast?

I already set my Function App to be Always On. I am just using the Portal to see the invocation and my functions logs. Also I am using node.js and not familar with C# and the whole WebJob history.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that my functions were using all wrong connection strings. Unfortunately these connection strings were created by Azure Portal itself when I setup the integration via the standard editor. 
Once I corrected my EventHub binding via the advanced editor according to this: (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs):

```
"connection" must be the name of an app setting that contains the connection string to the event hub's namespace. Copy this connection string by clicking the Connection Information button for the namespace, not the event hub itself. This connection string must have at least read permissions to activate the trigger.
```

my functions were triggered almost instantly!

(Specifically, the bindings created by the portal use the eventhub namespace as the path, and the connection strings created have the "Endpoint" pointing to the hub.)